Interact with my program on react app
I am a begineer on Solana blockchain development.
I am trying to have my front end application built with react communicate with my program deployed on a localblockchain.
What I did:
Created a program with Anchor (very easy program):
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("EoyFN6SaRjUzcXJ2nUaDdiR1QBn2ukEGNDxjgetT4yaQ");

#[program]
pub mod solbola {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Greetings from: {:?}", ctx.program_id);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {}


After this I ran the command Anchor build which generaterd and IDL file that I copied into my react-app folder.
On my react app folder I installed the following libraries:
"@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.30.1",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.23",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.35",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.35",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.19.32",
"@solana/web3.js": "^1.93.4",

For the code I have 2 files the main one App.js:
const App = () => {
  const network = 'devnet';
  const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);
  const wallets = useMemo(() => [new PhantomWalletAdapter()], []);

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
      <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
        <WalletModalProvider>
          <div>
            <WalletMultiButton />
            <InteractWithSolbola />
          </div>
        </WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

I use the wallet-adapter library to generate buttons to connect and disconnect my wallet from the application. Works completely fine.
I also have my InteractWithSolbola.jsx file where I want to create a button that on click interact with my program and execute the initialize method.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { Connection, PublicKey, Transaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Program, AnchorProvider, web3 } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import solbola from '../solbola.json';

const programId = new PublicKey('EoyFN6SaRjUzcXJ2nUaDdiR1QBn2ukEGNDxjgetT4yaQ'); 

const InteractWithSolbola = () => {
    const { publicKey, sendTransaction, signTransaction } = useWallet();
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const connection = new Connection('http://127.0.0.1:8899');

    const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, { publicKey, signTransaction }, { commitment: 'processed' });
    const program = new Program(solbola, programId, provider);

    const interactWithProgram = async () => {
        if (!publicKey) {
            setMessage('Please connect your wallet.');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const transaction = new web3.Transaction();
            const instruction = await program.methods.initialize().instruction();
            transaction.add(instruction);

            const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
            await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'processed');

            setMessage(`Transaction confirmed with signature: ${signature}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Transaction failed:', error);
            setMessage(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={interactWithProgram}>Interact with Solbola</button>
            <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default InteractWithSolbola;

When I start my app connect my wallet and click onto the button to interact with my program I get the following error message: "Transaction failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encode')"
I am not sure what to change in the sendTransactions method in order to fix the issue as I basically followed a tutorial that is most likely outdated?

If you are on devnet, it's probably because devnet is down. Similar question https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/15072/why-is-the-createmint-call-not-working
